Quarkus extension: add deployment dependencies via quarkus CLI
I develop an extension for my quarkus application and therefore used the CLI command quarkus create extension ..... This created a maven multi-module project with the deployment and runtime modules.
The extension runs fine but one thing I noticed is, that when I use quarkus extension add ... the extension dependency is added to the parent pom.xml or the runtime module depending on where I execute the command.
Example:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest-openapi</artifactId>
</dependency>

If I run the command within the deployment module the extension is not added as deployment dependency but only in the same way as I declare it. Example:
quarkus extension add camel-quarkus-rest-openapi

Since I want to have the correlating deployment dependency in the deployment module I also tried to execute
quarkus extension add camel-quarkus-rest-openapi-deployment
[ERROR] ❗  Nothing installed because keyword(s) 'camel-quarkus-rest-openapi-deployment' were not matched in the catalog.


But this always resolves in an error.
When I try to compile my extension after this, it doesn't compile successfully because the deployment module is missing the correlating deployment dependency. I can add it manually there, but since I used so far only the quarkus cli for creating and managing the structure of my quarkus-extension I was wondering if there is an option or command to add the deployment dependency to the quarkus-deployment module as well?
I, at least can't find something in the cli help and in the quarkus documentation.
Do I really have to add the deployment dependency to the pom.xml by hand?

I would suggest opening an issue in the Quarkus repository for this

Until now I was quite sure that the problem is me and that I miss something, because it's so obvious that the CLI should do that, that there's no way that it's still missing :-)

When adding an extension using the Quarkus CLI, if you run quarkus extension add <extension> in the deployment module, it will add the runtime dependency by default, not the deployment one. To add the corresponding deployment dependency, you'll need to add it manually in your deployment module’s pom.xml.
For example, add the following to the pom.xml of the deployment module:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest-openapi-deployment</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Currently, there is no Quarkus CLI command that automatically adds deployment dependencies, so this step must be done manually.
